# Detect arbitrary input file changes for T4 text transform in MsBuild

Tags: msbuild, t4

I'm struggling to get a basic example working of T4 transforms with MsBuild. A library consists of a single input file (csv) which is transformed to a single .cs file, which is built to the .dll. The requirements are

- If the .csv file changes, the project should be rebuilt, including the transform csv->cs before compile, to keep the dll up to date.
- If the .tt file changes, the project should be detected as out of date (this works, even without transform-on-build plugins in VS)
- If neither the .tt or the .csv file has changed, the library must *not* be considered out of date with respect to its output dll. The project should build using the last generated .cs file, or be considered up to date if nothing else changed.
- This must work both using msbuild on command line and in VS

I have tried using both `Microsoft.TextTransform.Targets` and `Clarius.TransformOnBuild` without success. What does work as expected is that when the *template* changes, it rebuilds. But the template in this case is a fixed transform and its *input* (the csv) is changing.

Relevant bits of the csproj:

```
<Compile Include="Class.cs">
   <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
   <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
   <DependentUpon>Class.csv</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<None Include="Class.tt">
   <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
   <LastGenOutput>Class.cs</LastGenOutput>
</None>
<Content Include="Class.csv" />
...
<Import Project="blah\Clarius.TransformOnBuild.targets" />
```

The problem appears to be that both msbuild and the transform plugins (such as Clarius.TransformOnBuild) are only detecting changes to the *template* itself (the .tt file), not the input .csv file.

So what I'd like to do is have arbitrary input. In this case the project should be considered to be out of date with respect to its output if the template *or* its input .csv file has been modified. Is this not a supported scenario?

Similar question (I couldn't decipher the answers here though):
[TextTransform on MSBuild only when file modified? (or an alternate route of doing this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30484955/texttransform-on-msbuild-only-when-file-modified-or-an-alternate-route-of-doin)